# redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:1: malformed number near

Tags: exception, redis, lua, jedis

I'm writing a lua script in redis, and execute it in spring, the content is as simple as

```
local store =   redis.call('hget',KEYS[1],'capacity')
print(store)
if store <= 0
then return 0
end
store = store - 1
redis.call('hset',KEYS[1],'capacity',store)
redis.call('sadd',KEYS[2],ARGV[1])
return 1
```

but when I run this script, an exception throws

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:1: malformed number near '262b4ca69c1805485d135aa6298c2b00bc7c8c09'
```

And I tried the following script in redis-cli

```
eval "local s = tonumber(redis.call('hget',KEYS[1],'capacity')) return s" 1 001
```

It returns

```
(integer) 100
```

And the Java code is showing as follows:

```
String script ="local store =   redis.call('hget',KEYS[1],'capacity')\n" +
                "print(store)\n" +
                "if store <= 0\n" +
                "then return 0\n" +
                "end\n" +
                "store = store - 1\n" +
                "redis.call('hset',KEYS[1],'capacity',store)\n" +
                "redis.call('sadd',KEYS[2],ARGV[1])\n" +
                "return 1\n" +
                "\n";

        if(sha==null){
            sha = jedis.scriptLoad(script) ;
            System.out.println("sha:"+sha);
        }
        Object ojb = jedis.eval(sha,2,id,userName,id) ;
```

Now I'm so confused and any help will be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`jedis.evalsha`](https://javadoc.io/doc/redis.clients/jedis/3.0.1/redis/clients/jedis/commands/ScriptingCommands.html#evalsha-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.String...-) instead of `jedis.eval`.

The error you are getting is Redis server trying to interpret `262b4ca69c1805485d135aa6298c2b00bc7c8c09` as an actual script. To invoke a previously loaded script you use [`EVALSHA` command](https://redis.io/commands/evalsha).